# Why doesn't my page-mod contentStyle font-face rule in Firefox Addon work?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to inject a font-face into pages using the page-mod module in Firefox Addon SDK. Here is the string I've constructed:

```
var fontString = "@font-face{" +
    "font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';" +
    "src:url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') + ");" +
    "src:url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') + "?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') + ") format('woff')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') + ") format('truetype')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg') + "#glyphicons-halflingsregular) format('svg');}";
```

and I log the string to console after it's created and it outputs:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(resource://jid1-sqpdj54n2pcvoq-at-jetpack/firefoxaddon/data/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);src:url(resource://jid1-sqpdj54n2pcvoq-at-jetpack/firefoxaddon/data/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(resource://jid1-sqpdj54n2pcvoq-at-jetpack/firefoxaddon/data/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),url(resource://jid1-sqpdj54n2pcvoq-at-jetpack/firefoxaddon/data/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(resource://jid1-sqpdj54n2pcvoq-at-jetpack/firefoxaddon/data/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular) format('svg');}
```

I've tested that this output CSS works by copy and pasting it into a panel page and it works fine. The resources urls are correct. However, when I try and inject it into other pages as a contentStyle rule the page doesn't recognize the font. Here is my code:

```
require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: [...],
    contentStyle: fontString,
    onAttach: function (worker) {
        console.log('Attached');
    }
});
```

I've verified that `onAttach` is being called after each page loads. Also, all the scripts that I am injecting with the same page mod (I didn't include them in the code snippet for brevity) are being injected and work fine. Also, if I change `fontString` to something simple like `body{background-color:red;}` it also works fine. Why doesn't the page recognize the font?

Comment: Do you see any CSS errors or warnings associated with your code? Or, have you tried putting your css into a separate css file and using contentStyleFile? I don't think you need data.url to get the full resource url, relative urls should work.

Comment: No, relative URLs will not work in contentStyleFile. From the [page-mod API page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), >You can't currently use relative URLs in stylesheets loaded in this way. For example, consider a CSS file that references an external file like this:
background: rgb(249, 249, 249) url('../../img/my-background.png') repeat-x top center;
If you attach this file using contentStyleFile, "my-background.png" will not be found.

As a workaround for this, you can build an absolute URL to a file in your "data" directory

Answer (score 0):

This is a XSS restriction.  If it's possible to convert the font data to a data uri `data:` then that may work.

Otherwise you may have to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK) and we can get someone on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the timebeing, while thats a bug, try this method, use components so go `var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');` at top and then paste this somewhere:

```
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);

var css = var fontString = "@font-face{" +
    "font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';" +
    "src:url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') + ");" +
    "src:url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') + "?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') + ") format('woff')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') + ") format('truetype')," +
    "url(" + data.url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg') + "#glyphicons-halflingsregular) format('svg');}";

//var cssEnc = 'data:text/css;base64,' + window.btoa(css);
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
var cssUri = makeURI('data:text/css,' + cssEnc);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

to unregister the stylehsheet, do this `sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);`